# Can i place course grained settings in WebLogic to override logging level or settings defined in deployment EAR or WARS?

Tags: logging, log4j, weblogic8.x

Currently we have fine grained log settings for each .EAR and .WAR deployment package we put into our WebLogic server, is there a way we can override these logging settings at a higher level, say to disable all logging or to set all .EAR or .WAR logging settings to DEBUG?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that for each individual .EAR or .WAR application, by using JMX and log4j. Here are some links that might help you: [#1](http://www.theserverlabs.com/blog/2010/04/22/dynamically-changing-log-level-with-weblogic-log4j-jmx-and-wlst/) and [#2](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-27991.html). I have personally used #1 method in WebLogic 10, but I am not sure whether it works on 8.x or not.

Regarding doing it to every single deployment, I don't know if this is possible at all.

Hope it helps someway.